# How to count the values in a selected row with some condition - Potgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, countif, postgresql-9.6

I am looking for some built-in Postresql functionality which can count the row values (not columns) with some conditions. Some analog of

```
=countif(a:a;"Yes")
```

in Excel

I saw many answers to similar problems here on stackoverflow, but all the solutions provided when you filter data in table columns, not rows.

But I need to parse data in rows.

I don't like the solution with crosstab since the original select has more than 60 columns and prefer not to execute the same query twice (but I will if it's the only solution).

Some test example, where should be the last column "num_of_yes", which displays the number of "Yes" answers in a row.

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE main_data 
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
    job VARCHAR(255) default NULL,
    age integer  default NULL,
    licenseid integer  default NULL,
    account integer  default NULL
);

INSERT INTO main_data VALUES(1,'Jhon', 'Brown', 'jbrown', 'some job', 35, 11112333, 3333455);
INSERT INTO main_data VALUES(2,'Bob', NULL, 'bob', 'another job', 64, 1000500, 5555252);
INSERT INTO main_data VALUES(3,'Mike', 'McDonald', 'mike', NULL, 8, NULL, NULL);
```

Select query:

```
select 
    id, name,
    case when lastname notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_lastname",
    case when username notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_username",
    case when job notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_job",
    case when age < 16 then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "is_child",
    case when licenseid notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_licenseid",
    case when account notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_account"
from 
    main_data
order by 
    id;
```

I have the following output for my select query:

```
| id | name | has_lastname | has_username | has_job | is_child | has_licenseid | has_account |
|----|------|--------------|--------------|---------|----------|---------------|-------------|
|  1 | Jhon | Yes          | Yes          | Yes     | No       | Yes           | Yes         |
|  2 | Bob  | No           | Yes          | Yes     | No       | Yes           | Yes         |
|  3 | Mike | Yes          | Yes          | No      | Yes      | No            | No          |
```

I need to add the last column with the number of 'Yes' answers.

Th desired output should be like this:

```
| id | name | has_lastname | has_username | has_job | is_child | has_licenseid | has_account | num_of_yes |
|----|------|--------------|--------------|---------|----------|---------------|-------------|------------|
|  1 | Jhon | Yes          | Yes          | Yes     | No       | Yes           | Yes         |          5 |
|  2 | Bob  | No           | Yes          | Yes     | No       | Yes           | Yes         |          4 |
|  3 | Mike | Yes          | Yes          | No      | Yes      | No            | No          |          3 |
```

I am using Postgresql 9.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the row to a JSONB value and then count the values that are `Yes`:

```
select *, 
       (select count(*) 
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t) - 'id' - 'name') as x(k,v)
        where v = 'Yes') as num_of_yes
from (
  select id, name,
         case when lastname is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_lastname",
         case when username is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_username",
         case when job is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_job",
         case when age < 16 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "is_child",
         case when licenseid is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_licenseid",
         case when account is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_account"
  from main_data
) t  
order by id;
```

The expression `to_jsonb(t) - 'id' - 'name'` converts the whole row into a JSON value and removes the `id` and `name` keys from that. Then `jsonb_each_text()` iterates over all the key/value pairs and the `where v = 'Yes'` then makes the sub-query count those that are `Yes`

Online example: https://rextester.com/PLJA96007

---

Another option is to use the `num_nonnulls()` function:

```sql
select id, name,
       case when lastname is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_lastname",
       case when username is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_username",
       case when job is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_job",
       case when age < 16 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "is_child",
       case when licenseid is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_licenseid",
       case when account is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "has_account",
       num_nonnulls(lastname, username, job, licenseid, account, nullif(age < 16, false)) as num_of_yes
from main_data
order by id;
```

This is most probably going to be faster than the JSONB solution.

---

Note that if you want a true `boolean` column, the `case` expressions can be simplified to:  e.g. `lastname is not null as "has_lastname"` or `age < 16 as "is_child"`

Comment: brilliant--i was trying to use `string_agg()` to make it work, but this seems much simpler

Comment: @richyen: there is another option using `num_nonnulls()` but that requires to repeat the column names

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `array_length` and `string_to_array`

```
select *
        , array_length(string_to_array(replace(t1::text,t1.name,''), ',Yes'), 1) - 1  
from 
  (select id, name,
  case when lastname notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_lastname",
  case when username notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_username",
  case when job notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_job",
  case when age < 16 then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "is_child",
  case when licenseid notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_licenseid",
  case when account notnull then 'Yes'::text else 'No'::text end as "has_account"
  from main_data) t1
order by id;
```